# ¿Cómo hago una lista dentro de una lista con css hover?

Tags: html, css

Tengo que hacer que cuando se coloque la flecha del *Mouse* sobre la *Lista* se desplieque una *mini lista* en los ítems del 1 al 5 como se ve en la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Además, cuando coloco el *Mouse* sobre el primer *item* queda un espacio en blanco a la izquierda, tal y como se muestra en la siguiente imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código de ejemplo:

```css
.lista1{
    color: rgb(15, 66, 107);
    display: inline;
    border-left: 1px solid rgb(15, 66, 107);
    padding:1em;
}

ul{
    border: 1px solid rgb(15, 66, 107);
    padding: 1em;
}

.primero{
    border-left: none;
    padding-left: -1em;
}

li:hover{
    background-color: rgb(15, 66, 107);
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Ejercicio1.css">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Ejercicio 1 </title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Listas</h1>

    <ul>
        <li class="lista1 primero"><a>Item 1  </a></li>
        <li class="lista1"><a>ITEM 2  </a></li>
        <li class="lista1"><a>Item 3 </a></li>
        <li class="lista1"><a>Item 4 </a></li>
        <li class="lista1"><a>Item 5 </a></li>
        <li class="lista1"><a>Item 6 </a></li>
        <li class="lista1"><a>Item 7 </a></li>
    </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Solo pueden utilizarse **HTML** y **CSS**. No tengo idea sobre cómo hacer que al colocar la flecha del *Mouse* sobre las lista se despliegue una *mini lista* (que sea como en la primera imagen) y cuando se coloque sobre el primer *item* evitar que quede un espacio en blanco a la izquierda (evitar que quede como en la segunda imagen).

Answer (score 1):

Reescribí un poco tu código CSS, usando flexbox en `<ul>` para evitar los problemas de espacios que pueden haber si se usaran elementos inline-block. Normalmente no usaría elementos inline en las listas, tal y como lo planteas.

En cuanto al submenú (o minilista como tú lo llamas) que debe salir del item 2, en efecto, usando hover y la propiedad `position`, lo mostramos en dicho evento, posicionándolo según lo que necesitemos.

Faltan algunos ajustes y mejoras menores, pero esos los puedes completar fácilmente según como desees mostrarlos.

```css
ul{
    border: 1px solid rgb(15, 66, 107);
    padding-left: 0;
    display: flex;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.lista1{
    color: rgb(15, 66, 107);
    border-left: 1px solid rgb(15, 66, 107);
    padding:1em;
    position: relative;
}

.primero{
    border-left: none;
}

li > ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}

li:hover{
    background-color: rgb(15, 66, 107);
    color: white;
}

li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: 1em;
  width: 100%;
}

.lista2 {
    color: rgb(15, 66, 107);
    padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Ejercicio1.css">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Ejercicio 1 </title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>Listas</h1>

    <ul>

        <li class="lista1 primero"><a>Item 1  </a></li>
        <li class="lista1">
          <a>ITEM 2  </a>
          <ul>
            <li class="lista2">bla 1</li>
            <li class="lista2">bla 2</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="lista1"><a>Item 3 </a></li>
        <li class="lista1"><a>Item 4 </a></li>
        <li class="lista1"><a>Item 5 </a></li>
        <li class="lista1"><a>Item 6 </a></li>
        <li class="lista1"><a>Item 7 </a></li>

        

    </ul>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Aspectos a tomar en cuenta

Se deben tomar varias consideraciones en cuenta antes de intentar solucionar el problema planteado:

1. Para desplegar el menú tal y como se muestra en la siguiente imagen: [image: Vista Previa]
   Deberás anidar otra lista dentro de la lista principal que forma el menú.
2. En la regla `ul{}` tienes definida la propiedad `padding` a `1em`. Por lo tanto, el relleno en todas las direcciones sería de la unidad que has establecido, quedando como resultado lo que se muestra en la siguiente imagen cuando colocas el cursor sobre él: [image: Vista Previa]

### Lo más simple

Solamente tendrías que reemplazar una parte del código **CSS**. Por lo tanto, tendrías que reemplazar `padding: 1em` por `padding: 1em 0`, es decir, reemplazar esto:

```css
ul {
  border: 1px solid rgb(15, 66, 107);
  padding: 1em;
}
```

Por este otro:

```css
ul {
  border: 1px solid rgb(15, 66, 107);
  padding: 1em 0;
}
```

Ya que con `padding: 1em 0` estarías aplicando únicamente relleno vertical, donde `1em` es el relleno vertical, mientras que con cero (`0`) no habría relleno horizontal. Es decir, daría lugar a esto:
[image: Vista Previa]

Esto es cuando se coloca el cursor sobre él.

### Propuesta (un poco más compleja):

De acuerdo a lo anteriormente descrito, una posible solución práctica al problema pleanteado sería el uso de las cajas flexibles en los ítems, considerando el [grado de compatibilidad](https://caniuse.com/#search=display%3A%20flex) actual con los principales navegadores Web.

Por lo tanto, las reglas **CSS** podrian quedar así:

```css
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif, arial;  
}

.lista {
  --color: rgb(15, 66, 107);
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.flex,
.lista__item--inner,
.lista__item--outer,
.lista--enlace {
  position: relative;
}

.lista {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid var(--color);
  
  /* Permite establecer la anchura
     del elemento en función de su contenido */
  width: max-content;
}

.lista__item--outer:hover .lista--inner {
  display: block;
  animation: 300ms ease desplegar 1;
}

.lista__item--outer:not(:first-of-type) {
  border-left: 1px solid var(--color);
}

.lista__item--inner:not(:first-of-type) {
  border-top: 1px solid var(--color);
}

.lista__item {
  color: var(--color);
}

.lista__item, .lista--enlace {
  transition: 300ms ease;
}

.lista__item--outer:hover,
.lista__item--outer:hover > .lista--enlace,
.lista__item--inner:hover,
.lista__item--inner:hover > .lista--enlace{
  background-color: var(--color);
  color: white;
  z-index: 10;
}

.lista--enlace {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 15px;
  color: var(--color);
  min-height: 50px;
}

/* Submenú */
.lista--inner {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  
  /* En en este caso, se modifica el origen de la 
     transformación de este elemento desde la posición
     izquierda y superior. Esto adyudará a dar el efecto 
     de despliegue del submenú */
  transform-origin: left top;
  
  /* Se establece a -1px porque el border del elemento 
     padre es de 1px */
  left: -1px;
  
  top: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  width: max-content;
  min-width: 200px;
  max-width: 250px;
  
  background-color: white;
}

/* Animaciones */
@keyframes desplegar {
  from {
    transform: scaleY(0.5);
    
    /* 
       La propiedad transform: scaleY(0.5) junto a la 
       propiedad transform-origin: left top; permitirá 
       crear un efecto visual de un submenú que se desenrrolla.
    */
  }
}
```

Mientras que el código **HTML** quedaría ligeramente modificado con anidamiento incluido:

```html
<ul class="lista lista--outer flex">
  <li class="lista__item--outer">
    <a class="flex lista--enlace" href="#">Item 1</a>
    
    <ul class="lista lista--inner">
      <li class="lista__item--inner"> <a class="flex lista--enlace" href="#">Lista Nº 1</a></li>
      <li class="lista__item--inner"> <a class="flex lista--enlace" href="#">Lista Nº 2</a></li>
      <li class="lista__item--inner"> <a class="flex lista--enlace" href="#">Lista Nº 3</a></li>
    </ul>        
  </li>
  
  <li class="lista__item--outer"><a class="flex lista--enlace" href="#">ITEM 2  </a></li>
  <li class="lista__item--outer"><a class="flex lista--enlace" href="#">Item 3 </a></li>
  <li class="lista__item--outer"><a class="flex lista--enlace" href="#">Item 4 </a></li>
  <li class="lista__item--outer"><a class="flex lista--enlace" href="#">Item 5 </a></li>
  <li class="lista__item--outer"><a class="flex lista--enlace" href="#">Item 6 </a></li>
  <li class="lista__item--outer"><a class="flex lista--enlace" href="#">Item 7 </a></li>
</ul>
```

Dando como resultado deseado el ejemplo que se visualiza en la siguiente imagen:
[image: Vista Previa]

Para el caso anterior, se utilizó [la metodología **BEM**](https://blog.interactius.com/metodolog%C3%ADa-css-block-element-modifier-bem-f26e69d1de3). Sin embargo, pueden utilizarse cualquier otro método o crear uno propio.

Sin extendernos más probemos las siguientes líneas de código:

```css
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif, arial;  
}

.lista {
  --color: rgb(15, 66, 107);
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.flex,
.lista__item--inner,
.lista__item--outer,
.lista--enlace {
  position: relative;
}

.lista {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid var(--color);
  
  /* Permite establecer la anchura
     del elemento en función de su contenido */
  width: max-content;
}

.lista__item--outer:hover .lista--inner {
  display: block;
  animation: 300ms ease desplegar 1;
}

.lista__item--outer:not(:first-of-type) {
  border-left: 1px solid var(--color);
}

.lista__item--inner:not(:first-of-type) {
  border-top: 1px solid var(--color);
}

.lista__item {
  color: var(--color);
}

.lista__item, .lista--enlace {
  transition: 300ms ease;
}

.lista__item--outer:hover,
.lista__item--outer:hover > .lista--enlace,
.lista__item--inner:hover,
.lista__item--inner:hover > .lista--enlace{
  background-color: var(--color);
  color: white;
  z-index: 10;
}

.lista--enlace {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 15px;
  color: var(--color);
  min-height: 50px;
}

/* Submenú */
.lista--inner {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  
  /* En en este caso, se modifica el origen de la 
     transformación de este elemento desde la posición
     izquierda y superior. Esto adyudará a dar el efecto 
     de despliegue del submenú */
  transform-origin: left top;
  
  /* Se establece a -1px porque el border del elemento 
     padre es de 1px */
  left: -1px;
  
  top: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  width: max-content;
  min-width: 200px;
  max-width: 250px;
  
  background-color: white;
}

/* Animaciones */
@keyframes desplegar {
  from {
    transform: scaleY(0.5);
    
    /* 
       La propiedad transform: scaleY(0.5) junto a la 
       propiedad transform-origin: left top; permitirá 
       crear un efecto visual de un submenú que se desenrrolla.
    */
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="lista lista--outer flex">
  <li class="lista__item--outer">
    <a class="flex lista--enlace" href="#">Item 1</a>
    
    <ul class="lista lista--inner">
      <li class="lista__item--inner"> <a class="flex lista--enlace" href="#">Lista Nº 1</a></li>
      <li class="lista__item--inner"> <a class="flex lista--enlace" href="#">Lista Nº 2</a></li>
      <li class="lista__item--inner"> <a class="flex lista--enlace" href="#">Lista Nº 3</a></li>
    </ul>        
  </li>
  
  <li class="lista__item--outer"><a class="flex lista--enlace" href="#">ITEM 2  </a></li>
  <li class="lista__item--outer"><a class="flex lista--enlace" href="#">Item 3 </a></li>
  <li class="lista__item--outer"><a class="flex lista--enlace" href="#">Item 4 </a></li>
  <li class="lista__item--outer"><a class="flex lista--enlace" href="#">Item 5 </a></li>
  <li class="lista__item--outer"><a class="flex lista--enlace" href="#">Item 6 </a></li>
  <li class="lista__item--outer"><a class="flex lista--enlace" href="#">Item 7 </a></li>
</ul>
```

Se podrían realizar más cosas, sin embargo, no lo trataré acá para evitar que esta respuesta sea demasiada extensa.

Comment: Si llega a encontrarse alguna laguna en esta respuesta me avisan. Estaré dispuesto a corregirla.